# AcquireTokenSilentAsync for sharepoint site what resourceid?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, azure-active-directory

I am currently building an Office365 Website which manages your files within onedrive and your sharepoint files. Currently though I am having an issue in that if the sharepoint isn't a root address one (i.e. https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com) but is a seperate one (i.e. https://intergendev1.sharepoint.com/anothersite or https://intergendev1.sharepoint.com/sites/moarsite) I cannot acquire the token silently, in other words I cannot use my token from the Office API to acquire a token for the sharepoint site. My theory is that I am using the incorrect ResourceId or ServiceEndpointUri, currently I just use https://intergendev1.sharepoint.com/anothersite for both, and I am un-able to aquire the token, but it DOES work for https://intergendev1.sharepoint.com/.

Thanks for the help in advance. If it helps, here is my AquireToken code:

```cs
internal static async Task<SharepointApiClient> GetExtenalSharepoint(Uri serviceEndpointUri,
    string serviceResourceId)
{
    var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthority, new AdTokenCache.AdTokenCache(signInUserId));

    try
    {
        return new SharepointApiClient(serviceEndpointUri,
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(serviceResourceId,
                    new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                        SettingsHelper.AppKey),
                    new UserIdentifier(userObjectId,
                        UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            })
        {
            ResourceId = serviceResourceId
        };
    }
    catch (AdalException exception)
    {
        //Partially handle token acquisition failure here and bubble it up to the controller
        if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
        {
            authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
            throw exception;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error/exception that you are seeing?

Comment: I'll get back to you with that soon, currently can't get to it. But it's the one that comes up saying aquire silent failed and to use the non silent version of the call which requires the users re-auth. But it shouldn't have to.